# When can I use "の" instead of "が" with adjectives like "好き"?

Tags: particles, adjectives

There are some adjectives in Japanese that work as an English or Spanish verbs, and they use the particle "が". But sometimes I see them with the particle "の". Can I always use it, or there is a specific word?

Comment: I'm almost certain this question is a duplicate, but I can't find the original.

Comment: Well... when I wrote it there weren't any similar questions...

Comment: To be clear, の works like が with any verbs and adjectives as long as it's in a relative clause. "Verb-like adjectives" are not special here.

Comment: Search for 'ga-no' conversion for more information about の working as が in relative clauses. https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5728dfa81bbee0da7943b811/t/57999461e4fcb532086bf67f/1469682786689/01-MiyagawaEL.pdf